# The difference between Mast Cells and Basophils

Tags: immune-system

While reading the Wikipedia article on [Mast cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mast_cell), I came across something that confused me. What is the major difference between a Mast Cell and Basophil?

They both seem to do the same exact function: triggering the inflammatory response. The only difference I can pick out is that Mast Cells are kept resident in a tissue while basophils move around.

Is this the only major difference?

Comment: There are differences. This article is a little old, so advances may have been made, but try reading through it. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2847274/